# iOS - how to target the "parent" viewcontroller with initWithViewController

Tags: ios, methods, uiviewcontroller, parent

I would like to use a method in a viewcontroller that is the "container" of an other viewcontroller but not directly the parent. I display a popover containing a custom xib file. For that I have three viewcontrollers:

1) **popoverVC** managing the settings of the popover (like alpha value, any arrow, size, and the method I want to use from "outside" dismisspopover)

2) **customVC** with a xib file to change the content of my popover (some text and some buttons).

3) **mainVC** from where the popover is launched and where I receive some actions when interacting with my buttons in customVC. mainVC is the delegate of customVC.

My problem is I don't know of to call dismisspopover method in popoverVC from an action in customVC. At the very beginning I initialize my customVC like this from mainVC:

**mainVC.m**

```
    customVC *cvc = [[customVC alloc] init];
    [cvc setDelegate:self];

    PopoverController *popover = [[PopoverController alloc] initWithViewController:cvc];
    [popover presentPopoverFromView:textField];
```

I tried to instantiate a new instance of popoverVC inside my action method in customVC to be able to call the method [popoverdismiss]. But this should not be working since I will be targeting a different instance from the one I started with... And I would like to be able to target popoverVC like [self.presentingVC] but I am not sure the method initWithVC sets a hierarchy like this.

Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I usually go about having to circumvent the default view controller hierarchy is to create a property within your child view controller (I think `customVC`) called `parent` or something to that effect that's of type `mainVC`. Then either create a new initializer for your `customVC` that incorporates a field to assign to `parent` or just assign to it after you first initialize your `customVC`. Then whenever your `customVC` needs to ask the `mainVC` to perform a function, you can make a method call from `parent`.

Alternatively, you could just as easily make `parent` correspond to your `popoverVC` object, I'm not totally sure which object you need to access, but it should be as simple as creating your own property for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! I don't know why I instantiated a new object in my target viewcontroller instead of creating a property and setting it when I instantiate at the first time with the good viewcontroller.